How can I prevent the TypeScript compiler allowing me to call an object when I use 'noLib'?
The following TypeScript code compiles without errors.

Why is this the case; I'm calling an object, not a function?
How can I make sure that the compiler raises an error?

tsconfig.json:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noLib": true,
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./auto.dist",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "include": [
      "./src"
    ]
}

index.ts:
type X = {
    'a': number
}

const x: X = {
    a: 5
}

x()

globals.ts:
interface Array<T> {
    [n: number]: T
}
interface Boolean { }
interface CallableFunction { }
interface Function { }
interface IArguments { }
interface NewableFunction { }
interface Number { }
interface Object { }
interface RegExp { }
interface String { }



"This expression is not callable. Type 'X' has no call signatures.(2349)"

Please provide a reproducible example. The code that you posted in the question does not compile.

"Everything is callable with --noLib". Your Function definition says anything can be a function; you need it to at least be callable for sensible behaviour.

The Function interface has a  name property: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L75 and the CallableFunction interface has some more properties: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L313. I'm not sure, if FunctionConstructor is the actual Function interface: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L301. IntelliSense lead me to the first interface, but the third interface makes more sense.

If one of you makes your comments into an answer, then I will select it
